# outer Joining 2 dataframes with unequal datetime indexes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following two dataframes:

```
df1
                          Feb-14 
    date                                 
    2014-01-02 12:00:00       NaN    
    2014-01-02 16:00:00 -0.075000     
    2014-01-02 20:00:00 -0.075000     
    2014-01-03 00:00:00 -0.075000     
    2014-01-03 04:00:00 -0.069125  

df2
                         Nov-15
    date                       
    2015-07-21 08:00:00     NaN
    2015-07-21 12:00:00  -0.175
    2015-07-21 16:00:00  -0.175
    2015-07-21 20:00:00  -0.175
    2015-07-22 00:00:00  -0.175
```

when I use `df1 = df1.join(df2)`

I get :

```
df1
                       Feb-14  Nov-15
date                                 
2014-01-02 12:00:00       NaN     NaN
2014-01-02 16:00:00 -0.075000     NaN
2014-01-02 20:00:00 -0.075000     NaN
2014-01-03 00:00:00 -0.075000     NaN
2014-01-03 04:00:00 -0.069125     NaN
```

What I really want to get is :

```
df1
                       Feb-14  Nov-15
date                                 
2014-01-02 12:00:00       NaN     NaN
2014-01-02 16:00:00 -0.075000     NaN
2014-01-02 20:00:00 -0.075000     NaN
2014-01-03 00:00:00 -0.075000     NaN
2014-01-03 04:00:00 -0.069125     NaN 
2015-07-21 08:00:00      NaN      NaN 
2015-07-21 12:00:00      NaN     -0.175
2015-07-21 16:00:00      NaN     -0.175
2015-07-21 20:00:00      NaN     -0.175
2015-07-22 00:00:00      NaN     -0.175
```

How can I achieve this ? I was also not able with merge should I change something in the dataframes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple solutions for outer join:

```
#default left join, so necessary add parameter
df3 = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
#default outer join, no parameter necessary
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```